# Deleting record by Date using LIKE?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to delete a record in my vb.net program. One of my WHERE criterias is a date. In vb.net, I am not getting the milliseconds in the date string so I am just trying to use a LIKE in sql.

I have tried the below but get "0 Rows Affected" or "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

```
DELETE FROM xxx WHERE [Who] = 'test' AND [When] LIKE '2018-06-26 07:52:54:%'

DELETE FROM xxx WHERE [Who] = 'test' AND [When] LIKE CONVERT(datetime, '2018-06-26 07:52:54:%')
```

Comment: Do not use string operators on date/time values.  There are many functions that operate natively on these types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide a range instead. `LIKE` is for pattern matching with an `(n)varchar`; you can't check if a date/time is "like" a string:

```
DELETE FROM xxx
WHERE [Who] = 'test'
  AND [When] >= '2018-06-26T07:52:54'
  AND [When] < '2018-06-26T07:52:55';
```

Comment: I am still getting '0 rows affected' from this. The actual time in SQL is "2018-06-26 07:52:54.293"           DELETE FROM xxx WHERE [Who] = 'test' AND [When] > '2018-06-26 07:52:53' AND [When] < '2018-06-26 07:52:55'

Comment: I wouldnt say that using `DATEADD` and a parameter is hard at all, @Lucidic . If that isn't working you need to supply a way to replicate it, as that value is within that range. You do have 2 causes, so perhaps the value doesn't have `'test'`. Either way, I am confident this will work if the data exists in the table.